# Load DLL and create instances of interface implementations dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, load

I have many DLL connectors. Each DLL has too many methods inside. But each DLL connector contains the following two methods (byte[] Document = GetDocument(string, string, string);   and   byte[] Image = GetImage(string, string, string);).

What I'm trying to do is:
1- Select the DLL file at runtime.
2- Fill the three strings.
3- Pass the three strings to the methods(Mentioned above) inside the inserted DLL to receive the returned file.

I just want to know how to call the methods inside the DLL.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use reflection (of course).
Take a look at the [`Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netcore-3.1) class.

You can e.g. use `Assembly.LoadFile` or `Assembly.LoadFrom` to load the assembly.
To activate a type contained in an assmebly in order to invoke its member, you can use `Assembly.CreateInstance`:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\bin\runtime.dll");
TypeInsideAssembly instanceOfTypeInsideAssembly = (TypeInsideAssembly) assembly.CreateInstance(typeOf(TypeInsideAssembly));
instanceOfTypeInsideAssembly.InvokeMethod(params);
```

If the constructor requires arguments you can use the appropriate [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_CreateInstance_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_System_Reflection_Binder_System_Object___System_Globalization_CultureInfo_System_Object___) `CreateInstance(String, Boolean, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo, Object[])`.

### Example

The following generic example uses reflection to create instances of `TBase` located in a specified assembly, expecting a parameterless constructor. `TBase` can be a class (base class) or interface.
Types that are not `public` or didn't define a parameterless constructor are ignored.

```
private IEnumerable<TBase> GetInstancesOf<TBase>(string assemblyFilePath)
{
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFilePath);

  // Get all public types that are defined in this assembly
  Type[] publicTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

  // Filter all public types in assembly and return only types...
  IEnumerable<TBase> documentProviders = publicTypes

    // ...that are not an interface (as we can't create instances of interfaces)...
    .Where(publicType => !publicType.IsInterface 

      // ...AND that are not an abstract class (as we can't create instances of abstract types)...
      && !publicType.IsAbstract 

      // ...AND that have a public parameterless constructor...
      && publicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null 

      // ...AND are a subtype of TBase. Note that TBase can be a base class or interface 
      && typeof(TBase).IsAssignableFrom(publicType))

    // Take each collected type and create an instance of those types
    .Select(concreteInterfaceType => assembly.CreateInstance(concreteInterfaceType.FullName))

    // Since CreateInstance() returns object, cast each created instance to the common subtype TBase
    .Cast<TBase>();

  return documentProviders;
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void HandleDocuments(string assemblyFilePath)
{
  foreach (IClientMethods documentProvider in GetInstancesOf<IClientMethods>(assemblyFilePath))
  {        
    byte[] document = documentProvider.GetDocument(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

So to Use it in my code and to call this method:

GetDocument(String,String,String) : Byte

`               Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\bin\runtime.dll");
                byte[] instanceOfTypeInsideAssembly = (byte[])assembly.CreateInstance(GetDocument(byte[]));
                instanceOfTypeInsideAssembly.InvokeMethod("My Name", "My ID", "Phone Number");`

Is it correct?

Comment: The variable, type and method names are just place holder for your actual code. In your case you'd probably call `byte[] document = instanceOfTypeInsideAssembly.GetDocument(stringA, stringB, stringC)`. You didn't provide enough details. That's why my answer is that general. You have to create an instance of the type that defines `GetDocument`.

Comment: What details you need to help me exactly in my case?
Actually because I read a lot about it but did't understand what to do in my case.

Comment: You only need to replace the placeholders with values according to the placeholder's name. What is the type that defines `GetDocument`? Does this type has a parameterless constructor you would call?

Comment: How to know it's type? 
Is it this one==>  [Export(typeof(IClientMethods))] ?

Comment: The class name Which defines GetDocument.  Which class do you have to access in the assembly you need to load on runtime?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I got the answer from my friend now.
He said that it is not a class, it is an interface which is (IClientMethods)

Comment: But you should know that you can't create instances of an interface. An interface has no implementation, it can't do anything. It's just a contract. There always must be a class that implements the interface. You can only use classes. You need to find out which class you want to use. Apparently, this must be a class that implements `IClientMethods`.

Comment: Sorry dear for late reply again, My friend have just replied me. It is from type dynamic.

Comment: It's not. `dynamic` is a compiler directive that allows to define a variable that can accept any type. A class cannot be `dynamic`. A class is a type. There is a class inside the assembly you want to load. This class must (according to your provided information) implement `IClientMethods`. If `IClientMethods` declares a method `GetDocument` then this class that implements `IClientMethods` must also provide an implementation of `GetDocument`. Otherwise this class won't compile.

Comment: In order to create an instance you must always know the concrete type of this instance. E.g., you'd call `var client = new Client()`. When the class `Client` implements `IClientMethods` tehn you can invoke methods of this interface: `var client = new Clien(); client.GetDocument();`

Comment: It appears you are very new to programming. Are you sure you need to do all this? Why do you think you have to load this assemblies at runtime?

Comment: Thank you very much for patience over my questions. Actually, yes I'm new in programming.
I need to GetDocument from many DLLs. And I don't have all of them now to make them static.
I asked my friend about your answer, he said "I have to read the class name that implements `IClientMethods` dynamically (something like reflection and MEF architecture)"

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can use either MEF or reflection. MEF is a framework that allows loading assemblies dynamically. If you are comfortable with this framework and willing to add a dependency to your project I can provide an example which allows to dynamically loading a specified assembly and get all types that implements a specific interface. In conjunction with the `FolderWatcher` you can even automate this so that adding a DLL to a directory will automatically execute the DLL loading and trigger an operation to handle the new DLL (or documents). Do you want to use MEF or reflection?

Comment: Do you really intent to get e.g. five implementations of the interface, then call `GetDocument` five times to get five documents (in case there are five implementations)?

Comment: Actually, I don't care which one to use MEF or reflection(I think reflection is easier than MEF). But I prefer the one that you can help me with the most. Of course I will write anything in my code to solve this problem.
And i appreciate your help. And wish you give me any example or provide me with a solution exactly in my case.

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide an example. The example has the following constraints: classes that implement a specific interface or derive from a specified type must be `public` and must have a `public` parameterless constructor. Let me know if  this doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks it is too much helpful. What does this line exactly do (IEnumerable<TBase> documentProviders = ....)

Comment: I have added comments to the code that explain what is going on. I'm using LINQ to iterate and filter the types contained in the assembly.

Comment: I have updated the code to make it more robust. I recommend to use this latest version.

Comment: I'm receiving an exception saying, (could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'a path is here' in  the service model client configuration section, this might be because no configuration file was found for your application or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element)!

Comment: This exception is definitely not related to this problem or my answer. Are you using WCF? The exception seems to be related to WCF.

Comment: Yes, I'm using WCF but this error occurs only when I run this code.

Comment: I see, but it has nothing to do with the code. It's how you have configured your WCF service. Do you execute this code via the service? Have you tried adding the service configuration to app.config? If this doesn't help you should paste the error message to start a web search. You'll will get results targeting this exact error.